# How to store highcharts compatible json array data in mongodb

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mongoose, highcharts

I am trying to feed data to highcharts client. Currently highcharts expects data in below format.

```
    [
    [1515122457593,47,64.17,12.77,23.91,15969798], 
    [1515122497615,23.91,47.97,14.19,30.81,15969798],     
    [1515122537619,30.81,49.42,13.34,27.76,15969798],...
    ]
```

However, I could not find a way to store in same format in MongoDB. I think one possibility is as below.

```
{
{ "_id": 1, "time":1515122457593, "O":47, "H":64.17, "L":12.77, "C":23.91, "V":15969798 },
{ "_id": 2, "time":1515122497615, "O":23.91, "H":47.97, "L":14.19, "C":30.81, "V":15969798 },
{ "_id": 3, "time":1515122537619, "O":30.81, "H":49.42, "L":13.34, "C":27.76, "V":15969798 },
...
}
```

My questions are in both directions.
Direction 1: How do I make above mongodb friendly json format to be read by Highcharts OHLC. 
Direction 2: How do I store Highcharts friendly data series in Mongodb?

Kindly share example as I could not find online any snippets that could help and all my trials are in vain. I got a [hint](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/series/data-array-of-objects/) here, but could not develop it further for my OHLC format (I am newbie to JS and webdev)

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
chart: {
    type: 'column'
},

xAxis: {
    categories: ['Green', 'Pink']
},

series: [{
    data: [{
        name: 'Point 1',
        color: '#00FF00',
        y: 1
    }, {
        name: 'Point 2',
        color: '#FF00FF',
        y: 5
    }]
}]});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve the exact document structure required by Highcharts using the below schema:

```
var schema = new Schema({
  data: [[Number]] // array of array of numbers
})
```

Comment: thank you, but there are 6 numbers per data row, so shouldnt it be Number, Number, etc?

Comment: sorry missed it, its array of array of numbers, so it should work.. will try and get back, thank you for your answer.

Comment: I just tried, but could not push as desired again. Can you please check my [gist here](https://gist.github.com/parthi2929/0eb2ec94698c278bd1409ce7b559d32a). Instead of appending, it is adding new data row even when i use push.